# Java Sha-512 Message Digest with salting not matching linux shadow file hashed passwords

Tags: java, linux, sha512

I'm trying to produce the same hashes found in the linux shadow file using the MessageDigest, given the password, salt value and hashing algorithm, although the results do not match with what I get from the function below.

- Hash Algorithm = 6
- Password = mandar
- Salt Value = 5H0QpwprRiJQR19Y
- Expected Output = $6$5H0QpwprRiJQR19Y$bXGOh7dIfOWpUb/Tuqr7yQVCqL3UkrJns9.7msfvMg4ZOPsFC5Tbt32PXAw9qRFEBs1254aLimFeNM8YsYOv.
- Actual Output = ca0d04319f273d36f246975a4f9c71d0184c4ca7f3ba54bc0b3e0b4106f0eefca1e9a122a536fb17273b1077367bf68365c10fa8a2b18285a6825628f3614194

I have this function for generating the hash value

```
public String getSha512Hash(String password, String saltValue) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    String text = saltValue + password ;
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    byte[] bytes = messageDigest.digest( text.getBytes() );
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString((bytes[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I'm referring to [this](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/08/etc-shadow-file-format-in-linux-explained.html) website.

Comment: You're comparing two different things: The 'expected output' is a string including the hash algorithm, the salt, and the hash in base 64 encoding, the 'actual output' is the hash in base 16 (hexadecimal) encoding.

Comment: Also note that you are making assumptions about 1) the placement of the salt (and if it doesn't including any extra things) and 2) that SHA-512 is only applied once (and not in iterations like is usual in password hash functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passwords in `/etc/shadow` are hashed using the `crypt(3)` system call ([`man crypt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt)).

You can use the [Apache Commons implementation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Crypt.html#Crypt%28%29) which should mimic the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that the site you are referring to uses Perl's [`crypt()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt.html) which seems a direct call to libc `crypt()`. In [the manual of crypt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) is not specified how the SHA-512 hash is actually computed, but I searched GitHub and found [this ~400 LOC source file sha512-crypt.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/crypt/sha512-crypt.c#L416).

I read throught it and can't tell if it refers to some standard or if it's the only program using that algorithm. Since the SHA-512 thing also seems a proprietary extension to the POSIX standard, it's absolutely not unlikely.

You could ask the maintainer or the mailing list and report your findings back, otherwise if you absolutely need that functionality, you could write a native extension (don't know if there are Java libraries already available).